# Export SharePoint Wiki to PDF from the Command Line

Tags: sharepoint, wiki, wss-3.0, pdf, export

We use a SharePoint wiki* at the office to serve as a knowledgebase for our IT operations. Recently we went through a disaster recovery exercise where we realized we had a key hole in our plans: how do you restore the services if your instruction manual is down because some services are offline?

Anyhow, we did realize that the wiki angle was definitely something we wanted to keep, but rather that we should explore a way to create offline backups of the wiki which could be easily read using common software we should be able to setup without any knowledge from the wiki.

So, does anyone know of a good utility that can take a SharePoint wiki and dump it to PDF/Word/RTF/[INSERT HUMAN FRIENDLY FORMAT] easily from the command line?

*-Yes, there are better solutions out there. But this was easy and used existing infrastructure and generally does what we need it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that you were after a utility to create a PDF backup, but have you considered using a tool like [HTTrack Website Copier](http://www.httrack.com/) to take regular backups of your wiki site?

Comment: Thanks Andi, I was a bit too focused on the PDF angle so I didn't think about HTML. That should do very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

As someone who has managed a few too many Sharepoint servers/services, I have not found a utility that does exactly what you would like it to. I'm confident that one could be written, but I wouldn't hold our collective breath.

However, it is fairly simple to create snapshots of Sharepoint content or to archive/restore them.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766807.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc706872.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm veering towards the "I'll just have to write the tool myself" scenario . . . .

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create a view that shows all the pages in the wiki. The only issue is the ordering of the pages displayed. This [document](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:1vZcNM7VDvgJ:https://tlt.stonybrook.edu/FacultyServices/Software/Documents/Export_SharePoint_Wiki.pdf+sharepoint+export+wiki&hl=en&gl=ca&sig=AHIEtbReFt9I2PUQskCzmfhDsLNsWXofoA) suggest adding a 'page' column and applying your own order as you create pages. Then you can print the view, save the view as pdf or copy/paste to a word document.